# How to make particles move with object?

Tags: rendering, particles

I have a problem. I want to particles stuck with object and move with it. But, when I keyframed object particles didn't move at all. What can I do? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: You have set *Frame Start* and *End* to frame 1000. I'm surprised you can see the particles at all at frame 13. Just tested it with blender 2.92 and the particles become only after the start frame visible. Maybe it's cached?

Comment: no, Blunder, whey are emitted in 1 frame and keep its positions in next frames. Ivan, try to use Hair type, instead of Emitter.

Comment: oops, sorry, it's '1 dot 000', not a thousand / Once emitted the *Emitter* particles fly around on their own. They follow forcefields like wind, etc and you can make them follow a leader (boids) but they are not bound to the emitter.

Comment: Thanks. Hair is a solution.